# How to generate images which have non gaussian distribution with GAN

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, generative-adversarial-network

I'm studying GAN, and want to generate fake images which have non gaussian distribution because real images's distribution has non gaussian shape.

I drew 10000 images's histogram of summation of each pixel's value.
A image's summation of each pixel's value has about 50 (24x24 images).
And It has non gaussian distribution (has a left side tail).

[image]

I trained this samples with GAN, and generated fake images are similar with real images visually.
But distribution of fake images is showed gaussian.
My thought that it is not trained very well, because real and fake images's probability distribution are different.

[image]

How can I generate fake images with real images which have non gaussian distribution? I heard, in this case I should consider non parametric "latent space", is it helpful??

Please let me know helpful about this problem, like any scholar paper of knowledge..

Comment: By training the generator it should learn the distribution of the images which, of course, is Non-gaussian. Usually the latent vectors that serve as input to the generator are drawn from a Gaussian distribution. You could change that to another kind of distribution but it's not clear how that would help you.

Comment: @BjörnLindqvist You mean generator usually draw gaussian distribution. Thank you.